# Is there a way to test an app before actually publishing it on Play Store?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just finished up my game and it contains ads. Up til now I have tested my game with only test ads that are provided by Unity out of the box that are of Unity. I wanted to ask how do I publish my game on Google Play Store so that I can get the game to show real ads? Basically I wanted to test my app just for this, to see whether I get real ads upon publishing or not. Thank you.

Comment: You can just soft launch your app, you prolly have zero downloads without marketing anyway.

Comment: @Menyus thank you for your reply and yeah I think that's gonna be the last resort. But I just read that the tester links might take some time to be available to the testers so I'm gonna wait for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a "beta testing" option, the actual options available are; internal, closed, and open test options that you can use when you upload the .apk file to the google store.

[More about it here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en-GB)

The closed/internal one is the one you'd probably be interested in, with the closed one, you actually need to invite people who have a gmail account, so perhaps the internal testing is what you should be look at.

Comment: I have already gone ahead and added my apk or app bundle to the Internal Testing but it says that "A link will appear here once you publish your app". And I cannot seem to be able to get my app tested before publishing.

Comment: Update: I just read in the link that you sent in this answer and it says that it might take some time for links to be made available to the testers so I'm going to wait for that. Thank you so much for your response. Appreciate it.